# Spring Data R2DBC PostgreSQL not saving new record with UUID @Id

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-r2dbc

I have a simple entity, consisting of two UUIDs:

```
@Table("library")
public class LibraryDao {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    @NonNull
    private UUID ownerId;
}
```

I have a corresponding table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS library (id UUID PRIMARY KEY, owner_id UUID NOT NULL);
```

I am using the correct R2DBC drivers (`io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql` and `org.postgresql:postgresql`).

To this point, everything works. My applpication runs. But…

Because PostgreSQL does not – at least according to the documentation – have an auto-generating function for UUIDs, I set the id when creating a new `LibraryDao` instance.

However, when I call the `save` method in my Repository, I get an exception: `Failed to update table [library]. Row with Id [0ed4d7c0-871a-4473-8997-4c9c1ec67a00] does not exist.`

It appears that `save` is being interpretted as `update`, without a fallback to `insert` if it doesn't exist.

How am I supposed to insert a new record into my database?

Comment: I think/am sure [this(entity-state-detection)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites) also applies to r2dbc repositories...due to "r2dbc-limitation", you could introduce a `Version` field/column or try 2. or 3.

Comment: Version and Persistable attempted; both failed; there is no equivalent Factory to subclass for the EntityInformation approach (that I could find).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the PostgreSQL documentation, there is a way to auto-generate UUIDs using the pgcrypto extension (for v4 UUIDs). (Process based on using pgAdmin GUI.)

In the Query Tool:

- `select * from pg_extension` and check that pgcrypto is not listed.
- `create extension pgcrypto` to install it; it comes with the default installation.

Then, change the column definition with to `... id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(), ...`

And it works.

Answer (score 3):

However, besides my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70972454/14132343) about doing inserts using R2DBC `DatabaseClient`, there **IS** a way to do it using reactive repository's `save` method - by using [Persistable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html) interface, which is pretty straight-forward.

Its `isNew` method can be implemented using entity's `version` attribut, or by adding a new dedicated attribut (something like `boolean isAlreadyPersisted`) that could be set explicitly before invoking `save()`.
And maybe there are also some other ways to utilize `Persistable` that I'm not aware of.

Comment: you can edit your own answers, so that you can add this to the already existing one.

Comment: This definitely feels the cleaner approach, as it avoids manually creating SQL; I'll give it a try when I get a chance and change my acceptance if it works.

Comment: @Rick It works?

Comment: @denizeve Sorry it took so long. It doesn't work. The SQL in the stack trace (`SQL [INSERT INTO library (owner_id) VALUES ($1)]; null value in column "id" of relation "library" violates not-null constraint`) indicates that it's trying to insert without specifying the id; it's expecting the database to generate that itself.

Comment: We've already agreed that ID auto-generation is not (yet) possible with R2DBC, it should be provided "manually", as I suggested in the other answer. This answer is about making save() work, instead of doing update every time.

Comment: This approach, then, only adds more code, and more places for said code to break. With db-side suto-generation, save works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since R2DBC doesn't have (yet) auto-generation of UUIDs, and tools used inside Spring have their own mechanisms which prevent sending nulls to DB (so triggers to do the job can't be used) - maybe the optimal solution here is to generate UUIDs with Java (`UUID.randomUUID();`) and put them in Entities before sending the Entities to DB.

**EDIT - concrete solution:**

A minor problem with your solution is that the DB installation must be modyfied.

After realizing described problem with insert, I quit trying to do it using the repository `save` method and switched to "manual" solution using R2DBC `DatabaseClient`:

```
dbClient.sql("insert into product_price(id, product_id, price) values(:id, :product_id, :price)")
      .bind("id", UUID.randomUUID())
      .bind("product_id", 1)
      .bind("price", 10.0)
      .fetch()
      .one()
      .subscribe();
```

And here is the `DatabaseClient`, configured from `ConnectionFactory` and enabled to accept named parameters:

```
@Bean
public DatabaseClient dbClient(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return DatabaseClient.builder()
            .connectionFactory(connectionFactory)
            .namedParameters(true)
            .build();
}
```

The `ConnectionFactory` is also a easily customisable Bean I have exposed in a config class that extends `AbstractR2dbcConfiguration`.

---

And hopefully, `save()` in reactive repository will be improved to behave like its counterparts in other spring-data repositories.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. The internal structure of R2DBC (or some key part of the pipeline) is such that if the ID is supplied, it always does an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`. So the ID generation for the primary key *must* be left to the database, thereby falling back to my solution.

Comment: I have edited my answer with the solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've provided the `@Id`. The library needs to figure out, whether the row is new or whether it should exist.

Already answered by [Mark Paluch](https://github.com/mp911de) to this question on spring-data-r2dbc issues board. See [#275](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/275) for further reference. And also you can find useful information from [#49](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/49).

Answer (score 0):

I have read and studied the above and not only here, however, it did not solve the problem. This is not enough.

Your field (**Primary key**) must have a column type, for example, **serial**, so that the database can automatically, when inserting a record, increase the record **id**.

**Without this**, all other recipes **will not work**.

Answer (score -4):

The UUID can be auto-generated, if you generate it by yourself Hibernate sees the entity with an id and try to update it.

To auto-generate the uuid just use the following annotations on your fields:

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "UUID",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator",
)
```

source: https://thorben-janssen.com/generate-uuids-primary-keys-hibernate/

Comment: That works with JPA. I need a solution that works with R2DBC.